# Is there a standard function that computes `f x (g x)`?

Tags: haskell

I couldn't find anything on Hoogle, but is there a standard function or operator with a signature like:

```
func :: (a -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

I.e. given two functions `f` and `g` and an element `x` as arguments it computes `f x (g x)`?

Comment: You might want to also see [combinator S](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Examples_of_combinators), which is generalized by `(<*>)` in Haskell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`f <*> g`⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

See https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree.

Comment: Oh, yes! Thanks you. I should have known this myself.

Answer (score 10):

The function you’re looking for is `(<*>)`. Why? Well, it’s true that `(<*>)` has a more general type:

```
(<*>) :: Applicative f => f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

But consider that we can specialize `f` to `(->) r`, which has an `Applicative` instance:

```
(<*>) :: (->) r (a -> b) -> (->) r a -> (->) r b
```

…then we can rearrange the type so `->` is infix instead of prefix, as it normally is:

```
(<*>) :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> (r -> b)
```

…which is the same as your signature modulo alpha renaming.

This works because the function type, `(->)`, has instances of `Functor`, `Applicative`, and `Monad`, which are idiomatically called “reader”. These instances thread an extra argument around to all their arguments, which is exactly what your function does.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a special case of [**`ap :: Monad m => m (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:ap)

Here you should see the monad `m` as `(->) r`, so a function with a parameter. Now [`ap` is defined as [source]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#ap):

```
ap m1 m2 = do
    x1 <- m1
    x2 <- m2
    return (x1 x2)
```

Which is thus syntactical sugar for:

```
ap m1 m2 = m1 >>= (\x1 -> m2 >>= return . x1)
```

The bind function `>>=` is defined [for a `(->) r` instance as [source]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-703):

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
    return = const
```

(`return` is by default equal to `pure`, which is defined as `const`).

So that means that:

```
ap f g = f >>= (\x1 -> g >>= const . x1)
       = f >>= (\x1 -> (\r -> (const . x1) (g r) r))
       = \x -> (\x1 -> (\r -> (const . x1) (g r) r)) (f x) x
```

now we can perform a *beta* reduction (`x1` is `(f x)`):

```
ap f g = \x -> (\r -> (const . (f x)) (g r) r) x
```

and another *beta* reduction (`r` is `x`):

```
ap f g = \x -> (const . (f x)) (g x) x
```

We can unwrap the `const` as `\c _ -> c`, and `(.)` as `f . g` to `\z -> f (g z):

```
ap f g = \x -> ((\c _ -> c) . (f x)) (g x) x
       = \x -> (\z -> (\c _ -> c) ((f x) z)) (g x) x
```

Now we can again perform a beta reductions (`z` is `(g x)`, and `c` is `((f x) (g x))`):

```
ap f g = \x -> ((\c _ -> c) ((f x) (g x))) x
       = \x -> (\_ -> ((f x) (g x))) x
```

finally we perform a beta-reduction (`_` is `x`):

```
ap f g = \x -> ((f x) (g x))
```

We now move `x` to the head of the function:

```
ap f g x = (f x) (g x)
```

and in Haskell `f x y` is short for `(f x) y`, so that means that:

```
ap f g x = (f x) (g x)
         = f x (g x)
```

which is the requested function.